# populating datatable from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable

I am trying to populate a datatable with values from more than one table I can get the values from the first table but not the second or third

here is my code

```
 <?php
class CRUDController extends BaseController {

public function instances(){

$query = EC2Instance::select('instance_id',


                    'public_dns_name',
                    'key_name',
                    'instance_type',
                    'launch_time'

                    )->get();

    $c_num= Account::select('aws_account_id'
                        )->get();
    $t_name= Tag::select('value'
                        )->get();

return Datatable::collection($query, $c_num, $t_name)

    ->addColumn('instance_id', function($model){
        return $model->instance_id ;
        })

    ->addColumn('public_dns_name', function($model){
        return  $model->public_dns_name;

    })
     ->addColumn('key_name', function($model){
        return  $model->key_name;

    })

     ->addColumn('instance_type', function($model){
        return  $model->instance_type;

    })
     ->addColumn('launch_time', function($model){
        return date('M j, Y h:i A', strtotime($model->launch_time)); 
    })

         ->addColumn('aws_account_id', function($model){
        return  $model->aws_account_id;
     })
        ->addColumn('value', function($model){
        return  $model->value;
     })

        ->searchColumns('instance_id',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'instance_type',
                        'launch_time',
                        'aws_account_id',
                        'value'
                        )

        ->orderColumns('instance_id',

                        'instance_type',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'launch_time',
                        'aws_account_id',
                        'value'
                        )
        ->make();
}
}
```

I am assuming of course that this can be done